# Why does Promise.all() tigger Array.prototype.then if defined?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, v8, ecma

Having the following pice of code...

```js
const array = [
  Promise.resolve(1), Promise.resolve(2), Promise.resolve(3)
];

Array.prototype.then = function () {
  console.log('Why does this gets triggered?');
}

Promise.all(array)
  .then(result => console.log(result))
```

Why does `Promise.all()` by itself calls my `.then()` proto function on the Array?

Of course it must call `.then()` for each of the elements in the array. That’s  obvious. But what is the purpose of doing it over the Array itself?

*This behavior is happening on V8*

**To consider:** If you change `Promise.all()` to `Promise.race()` this does not happen.

I'm not saying this is a mistake. I just want to understand the reason. If you can quote the EcmaScript specification on the answer I would really appreciate.

**Update:** 
I know `Promise.all()` returns an array but wrapped on a promise. That is obvious too. If you remove the `.then()` like...

```js
Promise.all(array)
```

it still executes the `.then()`method.

Comment: This being a prime example of why it’s a bad idea to extend native types...

Comment: If this was real code: absolutely. But as a question about unexpected behaviour on the Array prototype during Promise.all, it's a _very_ interesting question, the answer to which probably involves the deeper parts of the Promise specification.

Comment: `Promise.all()` presumes its parameters are "thenables"; by adding a `then` property to the array, it became a "thenable".

Comment: @Haroldo_OK got specs or docs for that? Because [the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) only mention that the input has to be an iterable, which in no way explains why _its_ `then` gets called, rather than `then` on each of the elements inside that iterable.

Comment: Maybe it's that inside `Promise.all()`, when all the elements are resolved, the code itself effectively performs a `resolve()` with the array of values from the promises. *That* array will *also* have a `.then()` from the prototype, so the `resolve()` code thinks it's seeing a Promise instance too.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Exactly, and if you take a look at some of the polyfills out there for `Promise.all()` none of them makes a call to the array.then() method

https://gist.github.com/Rich-Harris/11010768#file-promise-js-L92

Comment: Indeed if you add `console.log(this)` in the `.then()` callback, the array is not the *original* array, it's the resolution values from the original array; in other words, the resolution value of the call to `Promise.all()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a `resolve()` is called, and the value passed to it has a `.then` property that refers to a function, the normal Promise mechanism will invoke that function. In this case, internal to `Promise.all()` an array of resolution values is built as each Promise in the source array is resolved. When that finishes, the innards of `Promise.all()` will call its own `resolve()`, passing in the  array of resolved values.

Well that array will *also* have a `.then()` value, inherited from the Array prototype. Thus that `resolve()` call will invoke the `.then()` method just like any other Promise resolution would.

[Promise `resolve()` in the spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-promise-resolve-functions)

Comment: +1 Right, for more details see step 10. b. from [Promise.all Resolve Element Functions](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-promise.all-resolve-element-functions).

Comment: Let me see If I get what you're saying. This has nothing to do with the `Promise.all()` method. If I wrap any promise inside another promise the interpreter will immediately resolve the internal promise. So I could never have a promise of a promise?
But it does that, right when I pass the "thenable" to the resolve method. A little bit confuse to me.

Comment: @IvánSánchez it *is* definitely confusing. When you `resolve()` a promise and pass a Promise (or any "thenable"; any object with a `.then` method) as the value, the Promise mechanism invokes the `.then()` method with a resolve and reject parameters as if it were a callback function you'd pass to `new Promise()`. Exactly why that makes sense kind-of escapes me; I think I understood it at one point but I'd need to re-read some good explanation. However that's clearly what's happening in your posted code.

Comment: Well, I still believe it's a little weird that the resolution of the inner promise happens when it's passed as the argument for the `resolve()` method instead of at the end with the `.then()` but, it is what it is. Sadly for me, this means that my proposal idea could never been make: https://es.discourse.group/t/allow-awaiting-on-arrays/178 Thanks for your time man